# echo product id and product_item_key in cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How can i echo product id and product_item_key of each cart item instead of total count ?

```
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {

    $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] = '<div class="header-cart-count">' . WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</div>';

    return $fragments;

}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Techno Deviser, probably by mistake, in the `foreach` loop set value to `$fragments['div.header-cart-count']` instead append it.

Try this modification:

```
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {

     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 
        $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] .= '<div class="header-cart-count">' .$cart_item_key.'<br><br>'. $cart_item['product_id']. '</div>'; 
     } 
     return $fragments; 
}
```

Or:

```
function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {

     $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
     if (!empty($cart)) {
         foreach ( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item )
            $output .= $cart_item_key. ' - ' . $cart_item['product_id'] . '<br>';
         $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] = '<div class="header-cart-count">' . $output . '</div>'; 
     }
     return $fragments; 
}
```

Comment: @JyotiSharma I just check second example from code above. If I have 2 diffrent products in cart, and click "add to cart" on next one, the `div.header-cart-count` index in JSON response has 3 key/value pairs.

Comment: yes you right , thank you ! all working fine, i am closing this topic now .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
global $woocommerce;
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

echo $cart_item_key;
echo $cart_item['product_id'];
}
```

OR

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
echo $cart_item_key;
echo $cart_item['product_id'];
}
```

OR

```
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
 $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] = '<div class="header-cart-count">' .$cart_item['product_id']. '</div>'; 
 }
```

This will give you product ids, instead of your current output.

Final Working solution.

```
 global $woocommerce; 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 ); 
 function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {
     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 
     $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] = '<div class="header-cart-count">' .$cart_item_key.'<br><br>'. $cart_item['product_id']. '</div>'; 
     return $fragments; 
     } 

     }
```

Comment: i have tried already like that but after that frontend make complete blank.

Comment: function.php file code
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 );

function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {
    
    $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] = '<div class="header-cart-count">' . foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
echo $cart_item_key;
echo $cart_item['product_id'];
} . '</div>';
    
    return $fragments;
    
}

Comment: You are doing wrong

Comment: what is right way ?
my target is to display each cart item_id and item_key after ajax add to cart triggered on category/home page

Comment: Try last step solution

Comment: I am just giving answer according to your question , with in your function.

Comment: thank you so much it is working as like i want.

global $woocommerce;
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'iconic_cart_count_fragments', 10, 1 ); 

function iconic_cart_count_fragments( $fragments ) {
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
 $fragments['div.header-cart-count'] = '<div class="header-cart-count">' .$cart_item_key.'<br><br>'. $cart_item['product_id']. '</div>'; 

 }
 return $fragments; 
     }

Comment: NO worries . so marked as answser

Comment: thanks but sorry it is showing only one product value even there lot of in cart 
i want to show all cart product id and item key